# Add Header Flag in YiiMailer

Tags: php, yii, postfix-mta, yii-extensions, amazon-ses

**Problem**

While Sending Mail via Postfix and through Amazon SES it throws me a ,

> 554 Message rejected: Email address is not verified.

Error message, And i have **verified my From Email address** and Amazon SES is in the **production environment** , so no issue there. This is what Amazon documentation says :

> **Email address is not verified**—Your account is in the sandbox and one
>   of the recipient email addresses has not been verified. This might
>   apply to "Sender", "Return-Path", or "From" addresses.
>
> If you have not requested production access to Amazon SES, you must
>   verify every recipient email address except for the recipients
>   provided by the Amazon SES mailbox simulator. You must also verify
>   your own "From" address. For more information, see Verifying Email
>   Addresses and Domains in Amazon SES and Testing Amazon SES Email
>   Sending.

SO, After searching for solution i found out a [BLOG POST](http://www.oneminuteinfo.com/2013/07/fix-amazon-ses-postfix-send-email-error.html) explaining the fix for this issue, which says adding `-f` flag in email will solve this issue,

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: michael@chtoen.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Return-Path: michael@chtoen.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: michael@chtoen.com' . "\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, '-f michael@chtoen.com');
?>
```

Which actually does solve the issue, But I cannot set it to the YiiMailer. For now i am adding this flag directly to php.ini as ,

```
sendmail_path to usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f "noreply@sbworkbench.com"
```

It works fine. But I don't want to do it this way.

**What I have done**

Is , Create the YiiMailer setup as ,

```
$mail = new YiiMailer('customerEmail', $data);
Common::setup_smtp($mail);
$mail->setLayout('mail');
$mail->render();
$mail->From = Yii::app()->params['adminEmail'];
$mail->FromName = 'PENDING NOTIFICATION';
$mail->Subject = $data['subject'];
$mail->AddAddress($data['sendTo']);
```

And for adding the flag I have tried ,

1. Adding the flag itself in the From address : Results the same
   invalid email

   `$mail->From= "-f exaple@example.com"`
2. Adding extra parameters "Form" with value as "-f exaple@example.com" : Results Duplicate Form Address (which is obvious :D)

**Question :**

1. How can I set header flag using YiiMailer ?
2. Is it related to misconfiguration of Postfix with Amazon SES ? However, The same setting is working fine for Java Application.

**P.S**

1. The code works on sendmail and swiftmail without Amazon SES with no
   need of the header flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YiiMailer is a wrapper for PHPMailer. You can set the `-f` flag by setting the [`$Sender` property](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=properties) of PHPMailer.

```
$mail->Sender = "michael@chtoen.com"
```